# Are the events in "The No-Brainer" part of the pattern?

Tags: fringe

In S1E12 of *Fringe*, "The No-Brainer", a jobless computer programmer creates a computer virus that kills people by liquifying their brains. It looks as if a hand protrudes from the screen, grabbing the head of the victim.

All events we've seen until this episode are connected to the pattern. This seems to be a standalone case.

I haven't watched very far past this episode, although I'm in the process of watching the entire series (so I don't want to be spoiled too much). Is this case indeed unconnected to the pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a link, but not a direct one. The killer, Brian Dempsey, was working in the field of biotechnology on the computer program that was able to kill people. It is strongly implied in later episodes that he ... (spoiler below)

> may have been working with/for the ZTE, who are hell-bent on weaponizing anything to prepare for the upcoming war.